# EF data to new pin location

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server database with Latitude and Longitude which I have imported through EF to my `WPF C#` application.

[image: database design]

Now in my application I have Bing maps imported where I want to create pushpins from the data I got through my EF query.

```
private void LoadPins()
{
    var result = (from s in PE.tbl_SafeSpace
                  select new
                         { s.lat, s.@long }).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    {
        Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
        pin.Location = new Location(result[i]);

        // Adds the pushpin to the map.
        bMaps.Children.Add(pin);
    }    
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong with putting in the data to the location but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Do not use images. Paste the code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Done thank you for improving my question.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I retracted my vote. What is the initializer of Location ? Are you getting some debug error?

Comment: I get a error at  pin.Location = new Location(result[i]); saying 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from '<anonymous type: double? lat, double? long>' to 'Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location'

Comment: Please specify the class Location. You can update/edit your question in order to put the information.

Comment: If you mean the Location of the pushpin its using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;
It expects 2 doubles.

or do you mean the location of class tbl_safespace?

Comment: I'll suggest you an answer, but if it doesn't work, please comment there and then we see how can we improve it and I'll update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion, please comment here if you get errors and I'll glad to update my answer.

```
private void LoadPins()
{
    List<Location> result = (from s in PE.tbl_SafeSpace
                  select new Location
                         { 
                           Latitude = (double)s.lat,                               
                           Longitude =(double)s.long 
                          }).ToList();

    foreach(Location location in result)
    {
        Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
        pin.Location = location;

        // Adds the pushpin to the map.
        bMaps.Children.Add(pin);
    }    
}
```

Comment: I think you were very close

but when saying 
Latidude = s.lat and Longitude = s.long it says Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'double?' to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Smmit well, you can convert nullable double to double with value??default like: s.lat??0 but your correction is fine too.